# Change pattern of a date object in Java and compare to another in database

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa, format

Could anyone help me how should I change a `Date obj` format: `Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2015` into `2015-02-01 00:00:00.0` from database?

I am trying to write search system in JPA based on many parameters - all work great expect of the `date_created` field of `Date` type in db..

Thanks in advance! :)

[edit]

Would it be better to convert both into `String`, convert and equal them?

[edit2]

Although it would be better to convert `Date obj` and put this into JPQL Query `query.setParameter("date", (Date) obj [not as String])`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's done.

I didn't even have to format this date, all I needed was using `[...] WHERE p.date = :date ORDER BY p.number` except of  `[...] WHERE p.date LIKE :date ORDER BY p.number` and playing with changing format of the date in `query.setParameter("date", date)`..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Date obj is your date to use, I'd use a simple date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String correctFormating = format.format(obj)
```